# Static enum class member

Tags: c#, .net

Can I declare my `enum` as a static member inside another class?
I want only one instance from this enum

```
public enum MyEnum 
{
    Add,
    Remove
}

public class MyClass 
{
    private static MyEnum _myEnum;


    public MyEnum Enum
    {
        get { return _myEnum; }
        set { _myEnum = value; }
    }
}
```

Is it Ok to do that?

Comment: It would be ok if you'd make the property also static.

Comment: If you're aware of what are you doing i see no problems. In some scenarios i have used a similar solution (static backing field and instance property).

Comment: what is the point in doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to make also the property `static` since it's pointless to get/set a static field from a non-static property.

That's not only confusing. I would call that begging for bugs.

Consider this:

```
var c1 = new MyClass { Enum = MyEnum.Add };
var c2 = new MyClass { Enum = MyEnum.Add };
c2.Enum = MyEnum.Remove;
Console.Write(c1.Enum.ToString());
```

What do you expect as output? Both instances now have `MyEnum.Remove` even if i only set one.

If you make it static above would not even compile which is a good thing.

You would need to use the property via classname which shows clearly that it`s a static property:

```
MyClass.Enum = MyEnum.Remove;
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your property as `static` too

```
public static MyEnum Enum
{
    get { return _myEnum; }
    set { _myEnum = value; }
}
```

Comment: Because it might be confusing. I (as a developer working with your class) would expect that an instance has it's own value and not a shared value over all instances of the class.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying :(

Answer (score 1):

It is totally okey asuming you will only access it through created MyClass objects. If you want to be able to set or get Enum without an instantiated object, I.E make Enum a singleton just as _myEnum, you should declare it static.